# RDF annotations for places

Tags: annotations, rdf

I have a Python list of tuple. Each tuple contains the attributes of a place. For example, within each tuple is a place category, place name, place lat, place long, and place description. I want write a script that annotates each of these place attributes in rdf. When I attempt to verify the output from the code below using the validator at http://www.w3.org/RDF/Validator/, only the lat and long show up as properly annotated rdf. How can I alter the code to properly annotate it? Note that place[0] is the place category (I didn't include this below), place[1] is the place name (e.g., Sears Tower), place[2] is the place lat, place[3] is the place long, and place[5] is the place description. Thanks.

```
        rdf_conversion.append("""

        <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
            xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
            xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
            xmlns="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/"
            xmlns:geo="http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#">

            <rdfs:label>"""+place[1]+"""</rdfs:label>
            <geo:Point>
                <geo:lat>"""+str(place[2])+"""</geo:lat>
                <geo:long>"""+str(place[3])+"""</geo:long>
            </geo:Point>
            <rdfs:comment>"""+place[5]+"""</rdfs:comment>

        </rdf:RDF>

        """)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add something surrounding to enclose your description, e.g. [schema.org](http://schema.org)'s Place type so that your example would look like the following snippet:

```
        <schemaorg:Place rdf:about="place[0]">
           <rdfs:label>"+place[1]+"</rdfs:label>
           <geo:location>    
               <geo:Point>
                  <geo:lat>"""+str(place[2])+"""</geo:lat>
                  <geo:long>"""+str(place[3])+"""</geo:long>
               </geo:Point>
           </geo:location>
           <rdfs:comment>"""+place[5]+"""</rdfs:comment>
        </schemaorg:Place>
```

btw, you could also utilise the better human-readable [Turtle](http://www.w3.org/TR/turtle/) syntax. Then your example would like the following snippet:

```
@prefix geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix schema: <http://schema.org/> .

<place[0]> a schema:Place;
  rdfs:label "+place[1]+";
  rdfs:comment "+place[5]+";
  geo:location [ 
     a geo:Point;
     geo:lat "+str(place[2])+";
     geo:long "+str(place[3])+"
  ] .
```

PS: keep always in mind the subject-predicate-object order of an RDF triple ;)
PPS: and make use of the recommended RDF libs

Answer (score 1):

You should use a library for adding tuple instead of trying to write the RDF/XML "manually".
For instance you could use [RDFLib](http://www.rdflib.net/) for Python.

If you want to write RDF "by hand", you should consider using [Turtle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtle_%28syntax%29) or [N3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation3) serialization.